# Reducing mySQL queries and time

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on speeding up a website, that is returning 300,000+ rows from a query. While I don't think this is too much of a load on the DB server, this query is happening in a while loop depending on the number of 'galleries' a user has.

For example Joe has 10 galleries in his account. Each of those galleries has x number of images, which have x number of comments on those images. So the query that is currently being run...

```
SELECT count(*) as total 
FROM galleryimage a 
INNER JOIN imagecomments b ON a.id=b.imgId 
WHERE a.galleryId='".$row['id']."' 
AND b.note <> ''
```

...is looking through all the galleryimage table 334,000 rows and the imagecomments table 76,000 rows and returning the result on each gallery. The query run on a single gallery returns a result in about 578ms, but with many galleries, say 30-40 you could be looking at a page load time of 17+ secs. Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue?

I cannot change the DB architecture....

Query for gallery id

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.created, 
       a.name, 
       b.clientName, 
       a.isFeatured, 
       a.views, 
       a.clientId 
FROM gallery a 
INNER JOIN client b 
ON a.clientId = b.id 
WHERE a.isTemp = 0 
AND a.clientRef = '{$clientRef}' 
AND a.finish='1'  
AND a.isArchive='0' 
ORDER BY created 
DESC
```

Comment: At the time of building the query do you have all the gallery ids ?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur - yes i do - updated question

Comment: you say you cant chage the architecture, but can you add tables?

Comment: Yes, adding tables is a possibility...

Comment: Well, first of all if you have all the ids at your disposal at the time of building your query, you can modify your WHERE clause to be of the type "WHERE a.galleryId IN (...)" where you replace "..." with the ids you have, separated by commas. Also, if you can index galleryId it would make the retrieval process much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consolidate the queries and eliminate the need for looping:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.created, 
    a.name, 
    b.clientName, 
    a.isFeatured, 
    a.views, 
    a.clientId,
    COALESCE(c.img_cnt, 0) AS gallery_image_count,
    COALESCE(c.comment_cnt, 0) AS gallery_comment_count
FROM 
    gallery a 
INNER JOIN 
    client b ON a.clientId = b.id 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT aa.galleryId, 
           COUNT(DISTINCT aa.id) AS img_cnt, 
           COUNT(1) AS comment_cnt
    FROM galleryimage aa
    INNER JOIN imagecomments bb ON aa.id = bb.imgId
    WHERE bb.note <> ''
    GROUP BY aa.galleryId
) c ON a.id = c.galleryId
WHERE 
    a.isTemp = 0 AND
    a.clientRef = '{$clientRef}' AND
    a.finish = 1 AND
    a.isArchive = 0 
ORDER BY 
    a.created DESC
```